# LibreOffice, SQL command with inner join

Tags: sql, libreoffice-base

my problem is that I only know the new name of the owner of the house with id_house = 10, so this code should work. If i try to run it in LibreOffice Base, it says unexpected end INNER, requires SET statement [update "t_Owner"
inner]
Can you help me?
Sorry for my bad english D:

```
update "t_Owner"
inner join "t_house"
    on t_house.id_ownerr = t_Owner.id_ownerr
set "name"='yes'
where "id_house" = '10'
```

t_Owner columns: id_ownerr, name, surname, address
t_house columns: id_house, id_district, id_ownerr

Answer (score 0):

```
 update "t_Owner"
     set "name"='yes' where "id_ownerr" 
          IN ( SELECT "id_ownerr" FROM "t_house" where "id_house" = '10' )
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it says unexpected end: FROM in statement

Comment: Do you need the quotes around the Table and fields names?

Comment: it says that it can't find the table. I have to use ""

Comment: so? Have you find out something? I really need this code

Comment: For sql is working, but it changes all names and surnames (name: yes, surname: false) D:

Answer (score 0):

In LO when using the default embedded data base, HSQLDB 1.8, queries (i.e. things that use a join) are not always updatability.  In fact they are almost always not updateable.

To test this for yourself try creating a query with your join and the fields you need and see if it's updateable.  Bet it's not.

You can move to using 2.3 (via a split database setup tool), or do what I do which is run in MariaDB and use a connector.